# My layout is disorganized when resize from four columns into two columns (responsive)?

Tags: html, css

I layout like :

[image]

And when I resize into two column I have new issue like :

[image]

I do not want to add height into column. How can I fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: give up float and use inline-block or inline-table instead. it will wrap into lines

Comment: please give your answer into bottom and I will mark your answer into best. Many thanks.

Comment: oky, have fun discovering display possibilities :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout looks like typical use of `float`ting boxes.

If you give up `float` for `display:inline-block;` or `inline-table;` your boxes will wrap into lines , no matter their respective `height`.

You can tune the layout with: `vertical-align:top;/* or any other value you need */`

Answer (score 0):

Apply float:left to the individual blocks.